# Vertical, Scrollable List of Panels with wxWidgets

Tags: list, wxwidgets, panels

I have a class `controlPanel : public wxPanel`. 
Creating a dialog I just put a list of panels in a `wxBoxSizer` in constructor.

```
controlPanel *cp[20];
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
     cp[i]=new controlPanel(this,true,"asd",i,i+1);
     bSizer5->Add(cp[i],0, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 0 );
}
```

But I can not scroll up and down to see all panels. What should I do?
Also `bSizer5` covers all other widgets, so `bSizer5` is in top of all.

Comment: You don't show enough code, specially about all sizers, to see what's going on. Anyhow, setting `0` as the second parameter of `sizer->Add' makes the added control fixed-size. Set it to '1' to allow it expanding with the rest of sized-managed controls.

Comment: Based on the name "bSizer5", I'm guessing your using wxFormbuilder.  If that's the case, try using wxScrolledWindow instead of wxPanel to contain your list of panels.